# In JQuery, how do I remove a comma after removing an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var body = 'Alex, <a href="blah" title="jason">Jason</a>, Kate, how are you?";
```

I want to use JQuery to remove the anchor element from body, and then also remove the comma after the anchor, if there is any.  Note: to make it easy, the comma will always be after the anchor with no other characters in between.

Comment: this might be one of those rare cases where it's actually appropriate to use a regexp on HTML...

Comment: did you want to leave the _contents_ of the anchor in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming (to maintain grammatical consistency) that you also want to remove the *contents* of the anchor.

Firstly, use a regexp to get rid of the comma:

```
var body = 'Alex, <a href="blah" title="jason">Jason</a>, Kate, how are you?';
body = body.replace(/(<\/a>),/g, '$1')
```

Then to allow jQuery to work on the string you need to enclose it in an element:

```
body = '<div>' + body + '</div>'
```

Then you can actually remove the element

```
body = $(body).children('a').remove().end().html();
```

NB: the code above will remove *all* `<a>` elements within the text, but leave other HTML elements therein untouched.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of removing elements like that then it would be better to encase them in something to "mark them off" as it were. You're saying that the name "Jason" is tied to the superseding comma, so mark them off. e.g.:

```
var body = 'Alex, <span class="name"><a href="blah" title="jason">Jason</a>,</span> Kate, how are you?";
```

Then to remove in jquery you can do something like:

```
$('a').click(function(){ $(this).closest('.name').remove(); });
```

This is the best way to do it, mainly because you have control over what is important to which text elements. A regex, or some way of removing the next single character will work in your example, however what happens if you want to extend your sentence, eg: `'Alex, <a href="blah" title="jason">Jason</a> (the farmer's son), Kate, how are you?'`.